# Is it a Software Problem'?

Tags: support, editing

My last two revisions on the posting "Is the Graveyard really so Serious?" at [physics.stackexchange.com/Questions] has not figured in the TOP questions list to be accessed through the link: physics.stackexchange.com. One is 3 hours old and the other is about 10/12 minutes old. Five hour hold revisions/postings of other posters are there. I have reloaded/refreshed the page several times .But this is not showing results------the revised posting/question has not shown up amongst the top questions. Is there some serious problem with the software?

I had sent an email at team+physics@stakexchange.com, informing them of the situation that the revised posting did not appear in the TOP question's list. The answer came:Ahh. Chances are you're just seeing a lag in the cache updating. It happens, and it can appear slow. Sometimes a refresh is all that is needed, sometimes it takes a bit more. I assure you, sir, that what you saw was likely perfectly normal.
However, should you spot it again, please take note and report it to us again. Repeated issues may well be a bug lurking in our midst!

Either way, thank you for your diligence. It is users like you who help us keep the Stack Exchange Network working at full steam. :)

--
Warmest regards,

Stack Exchange Team

"That was 14th May 10:54 AM,Indian standard time.Later on further queries I was informed by email that low sore questions are not shown.That was 15 May,11:51

Answer (score 4):

Because the question currently has a net score below -3 it will not appear on the  front page (http://physics.stackexchage.com/).

This is by design.

I can't find an authoritative source just now, but this is alluded to in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/2509.

Comment: I had sent a mail at team+physics@stakexchange.com, informing them of the situation that the revised posting did not appear in the TOP question's list. The answer came:Ahh. Chances are you're just seeing a lag in the cache updating. It happens, and it can appear slow. Sometimes a refresh is all that is needed, sometimes it takes a bit more. I assure you, sir, that what you saw was likely perfectly normal."That was 14th May 10:54 AM,Indian standard time.Later on further queries I was informed by email that low sore questions are not shown.That was 15 May,11:51 PM

Comment: (in continuation) by that time the meta answer had appeared